# Quickly convert and merge image attachments in email to pdf

Tags: email, pdf

Yesterday I had to go through many emails, save multiple images from each (mostly jpg, though not exclusively), upload them to pdfs, and then merge the pdfs together, and this took a substantially amount of time. Is there any nice way to speed up this process a lot? It would be appreciated.

Comment: When in Outlook, for any message, you can save all attachments in the message at one go. If you use the same folder, you can do this for each message. So about 10 seconds, maybe 15 seconds per message (do save locally here).  Then when done, highlight all the files, right click and combine using Acrobat Pro DC.  I have done this on a small scale. In native Outlook that is about all you can do and I have not seen a third party app to do this.

Comment: What email program are you using? What operating system?

Comment: I just use gmail in browser, but would be willing to use something else to speed up this process. OS is Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to save bulk emails. If you use Outlook (you can add other emails besides .outlook or .live to the Outlook program) you can download a third party "Add-in" called Kutools. This will allow you to bulk downloads emails as PDF or other formats.

However, if you are trying to only download in bulk the attachments in the emails and not the actual emails (like i suspect you are describing) then there is no known services offering this option.

You can speed up combining the documents into one PDF by using Adobe Acrobat. That is the best software out there to combine PDFs.